# How to access a (shadowed) global function in ruby

Tags: ruby, scope

I was wondering how to access a global function `fn` in ruby from a class which also defined a method `fn`. I have made a workaround by aliasing the function like so:

```
def fn
end

class Bar
    alias global_fn fn
    def fn
        # how to access the global fn here without the alias
        global_fn
    end
end
```

I'm looking for something along the lines of c++'s :: to access global scope but I can't seem to locate any information about it. I guess I don't know specifically what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the top-level a `def` adds a private method to `Object`.

I can think of three ways to get the top-level function:

(1) Use `send` to invoke the private method on `Object` itself (only works if the method is not a mutator since `Object` will be the receiver)

```
Object.send(:fn)
```

(2) Get a `Method` instance of the top-level method and bind it to the instance you want to invoke it on:

```
class Bar
  def fn
    Object.instance_method(:fn).bind(self).call
  end
end
```

(3) Use `super` (assumes no super classes of `Bar` below `Object` redefine the function)

```
class Bar
  def fn
    super
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

Since solution (2) is the preferable one (in my opinion) we can try to improve the syntax by defining a utility method on `Object` called `super_method`:

```
class Object
  def super_method(base, meth, *args, &block)
    if !self.kind_of?(base) 
      raise ArgumentError, "#{base} is not a superclass of #{self}" 
    end

    base.instance_method(meth).bind(self).call(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

Use like the following:

```
class Bar
  def fn
    super_method Object, :fn
  end
end
```

Where the first argument to `super_method` must be a valid superclass of `Bar`, the second argument the method you want to invoke, and all remaining arguments (if any) are passed along as parameters to the selected method.

Comment: I didn't know that global methods are actually added to Object. Does this mean that my alias approach, like your super approach will also break also if Bar has a superclass which also defines fn?

Comment: @yngvedh, exactly. It'll break in the same way. The most general approach IMO is to use the second solution.

Comment: @banister, and there is no other way to accomplish that? I'm thinking of something more syntactically pleasing, like c++'s Object::fn.

Comment: @yngvedh, just updated with a method on `Object` that hopefully improves the syntax for you

Comment: @yngvedh, it just occurred to me that a 'global function' should never really be a mutator method anyway, and so perhaps solution (1) is best for you. However, in the general case...i.e to invoke a method defined on an arbitrary baseclass somewhere in the inheritance chain, i think the `super_method` approach is a good one ;)

Comment: @banister Can you elaborate the mutator part? Why can't it be mutator? Why shouldn't it be mutator?