# Forcing Kernel::method_name to be called in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to add a `foo` method to Ruby's Kernel module, so I can write `foo(obj)` anywhere and have it do something to `obj`. Sometimes I want a class to override `foo`, so I do this:

```
module Kernel
  private  # important; this is what Ruby does for commands like 'puts', etc.
  def foo x
    if x.respond_to? :foo
      x.foo  # use overwritten method.
    else
      # do something to x.
    end
  end
end
```

this is good, and works. but, what if I want to use the default `Kernel::foo` in some other object that overwrites `foo`? Since I've got an instance method `foo`, I've lost the original binding to `Kernel::foo`.

```
class Bar
  def foo  # override behaviour of Kernel::foo for Bar objects.
    foo(3) # calls Bar::foo, not the desired call of Kernel::foo.
    Kernel::foo(3)  # can't call Kernel::foo because it's private.
    # question: how do I call Kernel::foo on 3?
  end
end
```

**Is there any clean way to get around this? I'd rather not have two different names, and I definitely don't want to make `Kernel::foo` public.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `super` keyword to call the superclass's implementation from a overridden method.

```
class Bar
  def foo  # override behaviour of Kernel::foo for Bar objects.
    super
    # do something else here
  end
end
```

Comment: yep, you're absolute right. thanks. got distracted by the obscurity of `Kernel`.

Answer (score 3):

For a more general solution than just `super` (super wont always work), also see this thread:

[How to access a shadowed global function in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681895/how-to-access-a-shadowed-global-function-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `alias` or `alias_method` *before* you redefine Kernel.foo to keep a reference to the original version.

Comment: I'd already tried this and it doesn't work, since `Kernel::foo` hasn't been mixed in at the point of code definition.

Comment: this can also pollute your namespace.

Comment: It *does* pollute the namespace in every case, but it answers the question that was asked.