# If I define a method in Ruby, does it belong to any class?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I have feeling, that if one defines a method

```
def test
  puts 'Hi'
end
```

then there is a class to which this method belongs to (i.e. `Unknown#test`). So one probably has a possibility to list all methods defined "outside" of other classes. Or there is another way to do such listing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define a method outside of any class, it will become a private method of the `Object` class.

Answer (score 4):

A top-level method is a private method of `Object`.
Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681895/how-to-access-a-shadowed-global-function-in-ruby).

Answer (score 4):

In future, to find what object a method belongs to, do this:

```
method(:test).owner
```

Output, for your example is `Object`

Answer (score 1):

And you can then list all the methods of Object with

```
Object.send(:methods)
```

or

```
Object.send(:private_methods)
```