# How to call a method from the global scope with same name as an instance method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have the global method `hello(name)` and an instance method `hello` like this:

```
def hello(name)
  puts("Hello " + name)
end

class String
  def hello
    hello(self)         # does not work, see below
  end
end
```

I want to be able to say

```
"world".hello()
```

but ruby won't let me. It complains

```
in `hello': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your method `hello` was shadowed by the method `String#hello`. See [How to access a (shadowed) global function in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681895/how-to-access-a-shadowed-global-function-in-ruby) for an explantion how to call it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
class String
  def hello
    Kernel.send(:hello,self)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This question answers this exact question: [How to access a (shadowed) global function in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681895/how-to-access-a-shadowed-global-function-in-ruby)

Basically, `def` on the global object creates a private method on `Object`, so you have to jump through some hoops to call it.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.send(:hello,self)` also works.

Answer (score 0):

Create alias for global method:

```
alias hello_global hello
```